# Only display hours if time is greater than 60 minutes

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-2011, time-tracking

I'm using a time-tracking sheet that calculates the time spent on a job by doing a simple subtraction between a start time and an end time in two cells.

The `hh:mm` format would suffice in this case, or as a small modification I'm using `[h] "h" mm "m"`, but the issue with both is that I do not want the hours to display when there are none (when hours = 0).

If for example 35 minutes are logged I would like the output to be `35 m` and not `0 h 35 m`. The `[mm]` format might be an option then, but I would still like my time above 60 minutes to be displayed as `1 h 30 m`, and not `90 m`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

`[<0.04166666][mm] "m";[h] "h" mm "m"`

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for the solution, just had to replace the . with a , after the zero duo to the system settings.

Comment: This worked for me, and I improved it for my own use by making it so only 1 digit is display for minutes, if its less than 10 minutes. Also, I made it display the seconds. If any wants to use this format: `[<0.00693][m]"m" ss"s";[<0.04166666][mm]"m" ss"s";[h]"h" mm"m" ss"s"`

Answer (score 0):

Not at all elegant, but how about this:

=IF(HOUR(time)<1,MINUTE(time)&"m",HOUR(time)&"h "&MINUTE(time)&"m")

Returns a cell value 02:24:00 as "2h 24m"
and a cell value 00:14:24 as "14m"